# is_home doesn't affect content

Tags: ajax, home-url

I have a bunch of html i need to show only if it is a homepage. My theme pulls content from AJAX and then changes the URL to reflect the new content change. in the meantime, the homepage content (the entirety of which is contained in the footer) still remains below, what i need to happen is the footer content should still be there but the content under 
`<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>` disappears. there is a close button included on each page, when it's clicked the AJAX content is removed and the page returns to the homepage, i need the is_home content to come back at this point. What happens right now is that the content does not go away when the url chnages, and when the ajax content is removed and the page scrolls back to the homepage area and the url goes back to home, i simply get the background no content. My entire footer file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Xpjc0vrG (the issue begins at line 46. ). The actual site is HERE: http://onthemouse.com/. the content i need gone when not in home is the grey stuff under the carousel 
you can see the custom.js file here http://pastebin.com/i4cQRS27, this file handles all the ajax requests, but i'm not sure which part actually pulls the page content. i added code on limnes 261 and 594 to try and make this work, hasnt so far. I think the url chnage and ajax content starts at LINE 236.

Comment: This is really a javascript issue and not specific to WordPress. give your home content in `#work-detail-wrapper` a different id and amend the javascript function that loads content to hide/show this div. right now it's getting overwritten when new content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to is `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`.

[is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) actually refers to the blog page (or the home page if you have it set to show latest posts).

[is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) refers to the page (regardless of whether it is a static page or a latest posts feed) that sits on the front of your site.

Comment: didn't make a different, i made the edit, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Can you please show us the complete code?

Comment: the full code as in header.php too? because the full footer.php in included here http://pastebin.com/Xpjc0vrG. but i think its most likely what Milo mentioned it looks like AJAX is overwriting the content, but this is supposed to work nevertheless..

Comment: Can you show us the code that performs the ajax request?

Comment: you can see the custom.js file here http://pastebin.com/, this file handles all the ajax requests, but i'm not sure which part actually pulls the page content. i added code on limnes 261 and 594 to try and make this work, hasnt so far.

Comment: i meant http://pastebin.com/i4cQRS27

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what's going on. This is actually going to be much trickier to fix and it actually has nothing to do with conditional tags. Without rewriting how the site works, you'll have to write up a custom conditional in the JS for hiding / showing the home page content. Are you comfortable with JS?

Comment: yes i use it all the time, i can work my way aorund it. I'm just not to familiar with how AJAX works..

Comment: In this case, hiding / showing the content has nothing to do with ajax. You need to look at line 295 of your JS file. In that section you need to add a check to see if you're own the home page (check the page URL), and then hide/show the content appropriately.